# implementing Inheritance in JavaScript in this circumstance [more specifically node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, game-engine

> I understand that it is looked down upon posting questions about a
>   programming language however I really can't seem to wrap my head around this
>   one and it is really demoralizing me.

I am writing a game in node js and I want to inherit from this class...I am not sure how though, the syntax throws me off and the tutorials for this stuff seems to do it a thousand ways all different from my approach, with a constructor and all.

Essentially my question is how to **subclass** the code below.

```
/* Character class*/
var character = function(startX) {
    var x = startX,
        swipe = 0;

    var getX = function() {
        return x;
    };

    var getSwipe = function(){
        return swipe;
    };

    var setX = function(newX) {
        x = newX;
    };

    var setSwipe = function(newSwipe){
        swipe = newSwipe;
    };

    return {
        getX: getX,
        getSwipe: getSwipe,
        setX: setX,
        setSwipe: setSwipe
    };

}

exports.Character= Character;
```

Comment: `var character` it first letter is lower case .. and in `exports.Character= Character;` first letter is capital `C`

Comment: in `nodejs` , which is run under V8 engine .. I prefer to use `Object.create` for prototype based inheritance.

Comment: Ahh, silly mistake.

I'll look into Object.create! Ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the code written in that form (where you're not using `new` and you have truly private data), the main stumbling block is that `Character` doesn't have anything that can be shared between instances. So while you can use the objects generated by `Character` as prototypes of other objects, you can't have *one* `Character` object and reuse it as the prototype of multiple derived objects.

Here's how you can write a function (`Villian`, say) that generates objects which each get their own underlying `Character` object as a prototype:

```
function Villian(startX) {
    var rv = Object.create(Character(startX));

    rv.doEvilThing = function() {
    };

    return rv;
}
```

`Villian` creates a new `Character` object and assigns it as the prototype of the object `Villian` creates. Of course, this means that every call to `Villian` creates two objects rather than just one as would be the case if there were parts of `Character` we could reuse between `Villian`s.

You could just have `Villian` extend the object from `Character` directly:

```
function Villian(startX) {
    var rv = Character(startX);

    rv.doEvilThing = function() {
    };

    return rv;
}
```

That only creates one object, and has no distinction between the `Villian` and the `Character` aspects of it.

---

If `Character` is written the way it is because you want `x` and `swipe` to be truly private (although as both have both setters and getters, I'm not seeing much reason for that), you might want to use the pattern that's going to be the basis of ES6's [private properties](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aprivate_name_objects), which unlike the pattern you're currently using, is friendly to shared prototype objects.

I've [written an article](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2013/05/private-properties-in-es6-and-es3-and.html) on how you can very nearly do that today without waiting for the new ES6 feature. In brief: ES6 will introduce new "`Name`" objects which are not strings, but can be used as the name of a property. That object can be used instead of a name when referencing the property. E.g.:

```
var x = new Name(); // Create the private name object
this[x] = value;    // Put a property on the object with that name
```

Private `Name` objects are opaque, and by default properties created with them are non-enumerable.

Here's the overall pattern. (I've tried to stick with your coding style here, apologies for variations.) Note that these `Character` and `Villian` require you use `new` with them, unlike your `Character` above. Below I show how to do this without `new` as well (it's a small change).

```
var Character = (function() {
    var x = new Name();     // The *name* for our `x` property
    var swipe = new Name(); // The *name* for our `swipe` property

    /* Character class*/
    var Character = function(startX) {

        this[x] = startX;
        this[swipe] = 0;
    };

    Character.prototype.getX = function() {
        return this[x];
    };

    Character.prototype.getSwipe = function(){
        return this[swipe];
    };

    // ...etc...

    return Character;

})();

var Villian = (function() {

    /* Villian class*/
    var Villian = function(startX) {
        Character.call(this, startX);
    };
    Villian.prototype = Object.create(Character.prototype);

    Villian.prototype.doEvilThing = function() {
        // ...
    };

    return Villian;

})();
```

Note that we now have our various methods on prototypes, and the properties truly are properties (whereas with the pattern you're using they're private, but not properties), but since no code outside our scoping function has access to the `Name` objects for them, no outside code can use those properties.

On ES5 and earlier (e.g., today), you'd need a function to stand in for ES6's `Name`. The one I give in my article just uses non-repeating random strings:

```
var Name = function() {
    var used = {};

    function Name() {
        var length, str;

        do {
            length = 5 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            str = "_";
            while (length--) {
                str += String.fromCharCode(32 + Math.floor(95 * Math.random()));
            }
        }
        while (used[str]);
        used[str] = true;
        return new String(str); // Since this is called via `new`, we have to return an object to override the default
    }

    return Name;
}();
```

You can do the same thing without `new`. The only thing that changes is the actual `Character` and `Villian` functions, but I'll include the whole thing for clarity:

```
var Character = (function() {
    var x = new Name();     // The *name* for our `x` property
    var swipe = new Name(); // The *name* for our `swipe` property

    /* Character class without using `new` */
    var Character = function(startX) {
        var c = Object.create(Character.prototype);
        c[x] = startX;
        c[swipe] = 0;
        return c;
    };

    Character.prototype.getX = function() {
        return this[x];
    };

    Character.prototype.getSwipe = function(){
        return this[swipe];
    };

    // ...etc...

    return Character;

})();

var Villian = (function() {

    /* Villian class without using `new` */
    var Villian = function(startX) {
        var v = Object.create(Villian.prototype);
        Character.call(v, startX);
        return v;
    };
    Villian.prototype = Object.create(Character.prototype);

    Villian.prototype.doEvilThing = function() {
        // ...
    };

    return Villian;

})();
```

Comment: I'll upvote that, but I'm not sure it's accurate to say that this code doesn't lend itself to being used in a subclass.  Ignoring the usual trope that JS has no classes, the code in this structure receives a large amount of space from Mr. Crockford as one of the 3 or so inheritance approaches Javascript has to offer.  And why not?  You're inheriting the character class just fine above.  The only downside of course is the *de novo* re-creation of all those functions.

Comment: I should really try to get through that chapter...The whole functional thing...man ha

Comment: @AdamRackis: True, you can create a *new* `Character` to use as each `Villian`'s prototype, I've added that option. It's wasteful, but possible.

Comment: @user2783087: I've added a couple of further options for you. If you're doing nested hierarchies, you may be interested in my [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) script that handles all the plumbing for you. `Lineage` is based on using constructor functions (e.g., using `new`), but you seem to think in terms of classes anyway, so... :-)

Comment: Your kindness has blown me away, sir. Thank you so much for your incredible answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more traditional inheritance approach, why not modify your character function to leverage function prototypes?

```
var Character = function(startX) {
    this.x = startX;
    this.swipe = 0;
}

Character.prototype.getX = function() {
    return this.x;
};

Character.prototype.getSwipe = function(){
    return this.swipe;
};

Character.prototype.setX = function(newX) {
    this.x = newX;
};

Character.prototype.setSwipe = function(newSwipe){
    this.swipe = newSwipe;
};


function Villian(startX, villianStuff){
    //pull in the base Character's stuff
    Character.call(this, startX);

    //set up the sub "class"'s stuff
    this.villianStuff = villianStuff;
}

//inherit all of those public Character functions 
Villian.prototype = Object.create(Character.prototype);

//now add whatever new Villian stuff you need
Villian.prototype.whatever = function() { };

var c1 = new Character(),
    c2 = new Character(),
    v1 = new Villian();
```